# Getting current credentials in Powershell and pass them to SVN commit command?

Tags: svn, powershell

So when I do an SVN -ci -m "My reason"

SVN asks me for my password.  Is there any way that I can capture that password from the currently logged on user and pass it as a variable or the like to the SVN command?  I'm using powershell 2.0.  The reason is that the script will run non-interactively.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want passwordless commit check the sources out via `svn+ssh://` URI and use SSH public key authentication.

Comment: Ah - this might be the way to go!  Didn't even know that this option existed.  I am reading up on this now.  Thanks!